# Java - What is the regex for the following String

Tags: java, regex

I am writing a program that takes in a java file and checks each line for a string containing assertEquals and then replaces the string belonging in the second argument of assertEquals (that would be expectedVar and expectedVar2).

Say these lines are read from a file and placed on a string variable:

```
String myString1 = "Assert.assertEquals(outputMessage, expectedVar, actualVar);" 

String myString2 = "Assert.assertEquals(/"Hello World, /" + "Hello!", expectedVar2, actualVar);"
```

I would like to use a single regex from the Pattern Library along with 'group' and replace expectedVar and expectedVar2 or basically any string that lies in the second argument of assertEquals.

I was thinking to take in anything after the first comma and before the second comma but the myString2 could also contain multiple commas (eg. */"Hello World, /" + "Hello!"*).

I am not sure on how to approach this. I am willing to implement this differently if you have another idea.

Thank you in advanced

Comment: Will there always be 3 arguments? can expectedvar or expectdvar2 or actualVar have commas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use regex atomic grouping `(?>...|...)` >>

#### Java code:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class Main
{
  public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
  {
    String text = "Assert.assertEquals(/\"Hello World, /\" + \"Hello!\", expectedVar2, actualVar)";
    String pattern = "Assert\\.assertEquals\\((?>(?:[^,]*\"(?:[^,]*,)+[^,]*\")+|[^,]+),\\s*([^,]+)";
    Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher m = r.matcher(text);
    if (m.find()) {
      System.out.println("MATCH FOUND: " + m.group(1));
    } else {
      System.out.println("NO MATCH");
    }
  }
}
```

#### Output:

```
MATCH FOUND: expectedVar2
```

Test this code **[here](http://ideone.com/6azQl)**.